# Confused Man Seeking: "Warning: Cannot modify header information"

Tags: php, header, output-buffering

I'm very much wanting to see the PHP warning "Cannot modify header information". Why? Because it's sensible. You shouldn't be able to send headers after body.

But I can!! If I debug some vars in a controller and don't `exit` immediately afterwards, the script just redirects to the next page: all goes 'well' and I don't get to see my var dumps.

Where in PHP can I configure (?) that it doesn't buffer output? Or whatever it is that enables this strange behaviour!

Just to be clear: I **DO** want the PHP Warning and I **DON'T** want the redirect `header('Location: ...')` to work.

I'm pretty sure on my previous (local) server (both W XP) it did throw the output/header Warning...

**edit**
To illustrate, with the most basic code (that I don't literally use, but indirectly it's the same):

```
$form->validate($_POST);
var_dump($form->errors); // !!
if ( $form->noErrors ) {
  header('Location: '.$form->redirectUrl);
  exit;
}
```

**answers**
@Heandel Error reporting is everything (incl notices and deprecated etc). Shouldn't matter though: sending headers should be impossible no matter the error display.

@tandu I'm using [my own framework](https://github.com/rudiedirkx/Rudie-on-wheels), but that shouldn't matter either.

@ceejayoz There's not a single ob_start in my code. I don't use it. (The template ngin uses it, but the template isn't trigger in postback.)

@Itay Moav I'm not in a shared hosting. I'm working locally on PHP 5.3.0 (WAMP) on Windows XP SP2. On my webserver (a VPS) this doesn't happen: I get a nice PHP Warning.

**UPDATE**
Thanks Galen

From php.ini:

```
; Note: Output buffering can also be controlled via Output Buffering Control
;   functions.
; Possible Values:
;   On = Enabled and buffer is unlimited. (Use with caution)
;   Off = Disabled
;   Integer = Enables the buffer and sets its maximum size in bytes.
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to Off for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: Off
; Development Value: 4096
; Production Value: 4096
; http://php.net/output-buffering
output_buffering = On
```

Turning it `Off` did the trick. I want NO automated output buffering. Thanks!

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: Is there `ob_start` anywhere in your code?

Comment: do you say you have `var_dump($something); header('Location: url/url');`   ?
Are you buy any chance in a shared hosting?

Comment: Answers above in original post/question.

Comment: Can you please mark the chosen answer. You do that by pressing the V mark under the points that answer got.

Comment: Thanks Itay, I know how SO works =) I've accepted and answered a few times before. SO allows acceptance only after 15+ minutes (and I think that's a good rule), so I'll wait a few more minutes/hours. Maybe someone enthousiastic comes along and spins it all around. One never knows!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the php.ini file locate `output_buffering` and make sure it's set to 0

http://us.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering

Answer (score 2):

put `flush()` after the `var_dump`

Comment: This does the trick, but I'd like it to be automatically flushing all my output (or however one would say that =)).